# CAN Bus termination with CAN transceiver

Tags: can

I want to correctly wire a CAN bus. The problem is that both nodes are internally terminated with 120 Ω, and so is the CAN transceiver.

This way I have three 120 Ω resistors.

Would it be a way to solve this, by switching the transceiver with one that isn’t terminated, and place it between both terminated controllers?

Or does the transceiver need to be at one end of the circuit?

Comment: Ideally just remove the extra resistor. But practical experience says that having 3x120R termination resistors isn't a big deal unless you have very high speed or very long distances. Having too few resistors is the more serious problem, since it will almost certainly break everything.

Answer (score 3):

The device which can be configured to turn off the termination should be in the middle. Only ends of the bus must be terminated.

Comment: If its regular 1MB CAN you'll get away with some stubs up to 2m or so.